# Java Polymorphism: Please Help Me to Understand Polymorphism

Tags: java, inheritance, polymorphism

```
class ClassA {
    String whoAmI() {
        return "ClassA";
    }
}

class ClassB extends ClassA{
    String whoAmI() {
        return "ClassB";
    }
}

class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ClassA obj1 = new ClassA();
        ClassA obj2 = new ClassB();

        System.out.println(obj1.whoAmI()); 
        System.out.println(obj2.whoAmI());
    }
}
```

Output of the code above is:

```
ClassA
ClassB
```

In the code above output is as expected that I can see the methods of class "ClassB" when I am creating a reference variable of class "ClassA" and instantiating with "new ClassB();", but why it is not same in case when I creating the reference variable of interface "List" and instantiating it by using its implementing class "ArrayList" (I know that we can't create objects of interfaces directly)?

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List objList = new ArrayList();

        objList.add("One");
        objList.add("Two");
        objList.add("Three");

        System.out.println(objList.get(1)); // Only able to call methods of interface "List", but not methods of its implementing class "ArrayList. WHY?"
    }

}
```

If class "ArrayList" is implementing interface "List" then why I am not able to call methods of class "ArrayList"?

I know that there is some misunderstanding in my mind about the concept of Polymorphism. Please help me to clear that misunderstanding!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

polymorphism has two concepts about methods.

method overloading - where you overload/add/has different parameters in your method

ex:

```
class ClassA {
    String whoAmI() {
        return "ClassA";
    }
}

class ClassB extends ClassA{
    // you are overloading the method whoAmI from class A
    String whoAmI(String name) {
        return "ClassB "+name;
    }
}
```

method overriding - where you override/change the default function of a method

```
class ClassA {
    String whoAmI() {
        return "ClassA";
    }
}

class ClassB extends ClassA{
    // override whoAmI method change function
    String whoAmI() {
        //do something
        int foo = 5 + 10;
        return "ClassB foo: "+foo;
    }
}
```

and in your question

```
class ClassA {

    String whoAmI() {
        return "ClassA";
    }
} 

class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Object obj1 = new ClassA();
        obj1.whoAmI(); 
    }   
}
```

from your code snippet above you are referencing an object `ClassA()` to an `Object` WHICH the object does'nt have the `whoAmI()` method. you're saying that the `obj1` is a ClassA() type of object which they have different sets of methods.

```
        Object
       /
   ClassA()
       |
    method:whoAmI()
```

referring to the class hierarchy above. the `classA()` has a method of `whoAmI()` and the `Object` has `equals(), hashCode(), getClass(), etc...()` when you're extending to an `Object` the `super class` doesn't inherit the methods inside the `child class`. In your example since `ClassA()` is extending `Object` (super class), `Object` will not inherit the `whoAmI()` method but it is the other way around. the `ClassA()` will inherit the methods inside `Object`. and if you are referencing your `ClassA()` to `Object` and accessing a method inside `ClassA()` you need to cast your `Object` to `ClassA()` to tell the compiler that i am calling a method from `ClassA()`.

EDITED:

in your example the output is not the same because you are giving a reference of `ClassB()` to `ClassA()` that overrides the method `whoAmI();`

and in your `List` example, `ArrayList` implements `List` but the instance variable is A `List`. refer to "diagram below"

Custom class

```
Class A                       Class B extends A

method: whoAmI()              method override: whoAmI()
output: "i am class A"        output: "i am new class B"
                              method: fooMethod()
                              output: "my own method"
```

so when you declare a `Class A` object you will be using the class a methods,fields etc

```
ClassA obj = new ClassA();
```

once you change the reference object to `ClassB()` you will be now using the `ClassB's` overriden method/different sets of fields, etc.. but it doesnt mean that you can call `fooMethod()` easily because remember it is still a `ClassA` the methods in `ClassB` inside `ClassA` will be overriden.

```
ClassA obj = new ClassB();
// override whoAmI() method changed output
```

but when you cast the obj to `ClassB()` it is like you are telling the compiler that this obj is a `ClassB()` this is when you can use the `fooMethod()` because the compiler thinks that `obj(casted)` is a `ClassB`

```
((ClassB)obj).fooMethod();
```

i tried the best way i can to explain this the simplest way i know. cheerioo

Answer (score 0):

`Object obj1 = new ClassA();`

In this line, `Object` is considered the **static** type of the variable, and `ClassA` is considered the **dynamic** type of the variable.

Static types are always used to guarantee the **existence** of a field or method by the compiler, while dynamic types are what's actually used to **call** methods when the program runs.

The idea is this: since the static type must always be a **superclass** of the dynamic type, the static type is used to guarantee that no matter what subclasses you use as the dynamic type of the variable, they will always at *least* support the methods of the superclass. For example, every Object has a hashCode() method and a toString() method, because these methods are considered essential to all objects in Java. You would always be allowed to call `obj1.hashCode()`.

Because the Object class does not contain a `whoAmI()` method, however, the compiler will throw an error.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you had this

```
Object ref;
if (new Random().nextInt(2) % 2 == 0)
    ref = new ClassA();
else
    ref = new String("whatever");
```

Should you be able to invoke a `whoAmI` method on the object referenced by the variable `ref`? No. The compiler cannot consistently know what type of objects your program's variables will hold at runtime. As such, methods are resolved at compile time based on the type of the variables. The `Object` type does not have a `whoAmI` method.